# Adding horizontal menu bar in Social office theme

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1.1 CE.

By default, menu bar in SO is placed as a side bar vertically,that we can add pages.

But i need another menu bar in top of the page horizontally,that i can add pages.

How can i add this to the SO?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to work on theme. You can set it in navigation.vm